# Rails 6 Creating IF statement for conditional meta_tag based on DB value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

I have looked at multiple pages, but my brain cannot bridge the gap to how this problem should look answered.

Problem: I need very specific DB generated show pages to have `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`. I know this will require an IF statement somewhere. So it boils down to I need specific DB driven pages in my people index to not be indexed by search engines as their pages are really not supposed to exist. (If a `@person.position == "hide"` they need to not exist to a search engine)

Setup: My app is setup with a `layout/application` page that contains all html, header, footer, meta data, and a yield call for all of the data for each page shown in the browser.

I am not sure where the if statement will go. Will I need to add a call to the controller? The more I look at this it seems like a super sloppy approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the captures helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) to create dynamic chunks in your layout that can be filled in by the view.

```
<html>
  <head> 
    # ...
    <%= yield :meta %>
  </head>

  # ...
```

```
# app/views/people/show.html.erb
<%= content_for :meta do %>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<% end if @person.hide_from_robots? %>
....
```

```
class Person
  # Encapsulate the logic in the model
  def hide_from_robots?
    position == "hide"
  end
end
```

Another way to do this is by sending the [`X-Robots-Tag` header](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_meta_tag) instead of using a meta tag:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    noindex_nofollow if @person.hide_from_robots?
  end

  private

  def noindex_nofollow
    response.headers['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex, nofollow' 
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're really privacy concerned you could also flip this and always include a `'noindex, nofollow'` directive and opt in on the actions that should be indexable.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do that as most of the people want to be indexed. I am going to give your code a trial tomorrow, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank for you your help, this has put in the proper tags in the header! Now to let google do the rest. As a continuance of this, in the `def hide_from_robots?` How would I set 'position' to 'hide1' or `hide2`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completely but if you could do `['hide1', 'hide2'].include?(position)` or by using a logical OR `position = 'hide1' || 'hide2'`.

Comment: I tried the OR's and it works. Thanks for all of your help!!

Answer (score -2):

If you're using ERB to render your HTML, you can do the if statement directly on the HTML file.

```
<% if @person.position == "hide" %>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think it's the other way around. If it's `hide` then `noindex`. Also add in the answer where exactly OP should add the code. In <body> ? In <head> ?

Comment: @razvans Edited my answer to fix the logic. Since this is a meta tag, I'm assuming that this would go on the <head>

Comment: One more quick question on the logic, if I later have hide1 and hide2, would I then use `<% if @person.position == ["hide1", "hide2"] %>`?

Comment: Also, when I attempt to use this, I get a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `position' for nil:NilClass):`. I was thinking I would need to add something to the controller for the application, but just adding `@people = Person.all` does not seem to fix the issue. Also not the I have a lot of pages that do not call @people at all, will that be an issue?

Comment: @Argent The logic you posted wouldn't work because it checks to see if the position is equal to the array ["hide1", "hide2"] - what you want to check is whether hide1 or hide2 is one of the person's position, so that would look something like this `<% if ["hide1", "hide2"].include?(@person.position) %>`

For the error - you have to assign @person on the controller. As far as what the @person is supposed to be, I would imagine it's some query on Person, for example something like `@person = Person.first`

Comment: This isn't a great solution as you want to place the meta tag in your layout and its now cluttered with the responisiblity of a specific view. If you did do this you would have to check if `@person` is present.